# JQuery validate not implementing 'required' in email field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I've a simple HTML input:

```
<input id="email" name="email" value="" type="email">
```

and validate it using JQuery validate:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
      email: {
        required: 'true',
        email: 'true'
      }
    }
});
```

The rules are applied, I can see them in `$('#email').rules()`. However when I later run `$('#email').valid()` or `$('form').valid()` the input is marked as valid when empty, but invalid when an invalid email address is entered.

How do I ensure the input is invalid when empty?

Relevant JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ycypuy86/

Comment: Is this a simple typographical error though? I get that the actual fix itself was only a set of quotes, however the error wasn't made as a typo - it was made because of the unfamiliarity in difference between string and boolean. The fundamental idea behind that closure reason is because typos aren't useful to anyone in the future, but this specific case is likely very useful - I can see this being quite a common misconception.

Comment: I agree, I wouldn't consider it a typo. The confusion was exacerbated by the shorthand `email: 'required'` for `email: {required: true}`.

Comment: @Santi You may have a point, and thus I will remove the closing vote. I would rather invite future people reading this question to visit the official [required](https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/) method documentation before posting or looking for questions such as this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually set these without quotes?

```
rules: {
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      }
    }
```

remove quotes on your fiddle and it works.

Comment: Ya beat me to it, but I figured I could supply the updated JSFiddle I had to show that this change does in fact resolve OP's issue: https://jsfiddle.net/ycypuy86/3/